# How to get multiple different instagram user's recent posts using the Basic Display API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

**TL;DR** - can I create an instagram access token generator with the new Basic Display API?

I work for a web design agency building websites for other businesses. These clients often require us to add an "Instagram feed" to their website, meaning a grid that displays the X latest instagram posts from their instagram account, sometimes also including other information from the post such as the caption.

Before the recent API changes (introduction of the Basic Display API), our process for this was very simple. We would get our client's instagram login details, log in to their account and then visit https://instagram.pixelunion.net/ to generate an access token. We would then use this access token to make requests to the API and get the user's posts to loop through and display on the website. We didn't have to create an app and get verification, we simply visited that website and generated the token.

**So the first question is**, is it still possible to get our client's access tokens as easily as it was before/in a similar way with the new Instagram Basic Display API?

I did read through the new Instagram Basic Display API documentation and follow the tutorial to get the access tokens myself for a test user, but the process seems very long winded (i.e. recording a screen cast of how the app will work) and time consuming, so;

**My second question is**, if I do have to go through this long winded process from now on, do I have to create a new app for each of our client's feeds under an account of someone who works for that business, and go through the review process each time, or can I have one "master" developer account (i.e. my facebook account) that has one "master" app named something like "Access Token Generator" in which I can generate access tokens for each of our clients by getting them to authorise with this app, basically in the same way that the https://instagram.pixelunion.net/ tool works?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will have to follow the process as outlined in the documentation, there are no other ways to my knowledge. Creating one app will be enough though. You let your clients login, so that you can get an access token for them, and then you use that token to make the API calls to get the relevant data.